# How to Hide the Navigation Bar During Scroll in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, mobile, uinavigationbar

How can I hide the navigation bar that appears during scroll down on Android and iPhone devices? Please see the attached image for a clearer understanding of the issue.

[image]
Thank you!